# Paging 3 Library: Combine results of 3 tables sequentially

Tags: android-room, android-paging, android-paging-3

I want to use Paging 3 Library and combine results from 3 tables such that:

Result from Table1 are shown first.
When Results from Table1 has reached end of their data then results from Table2 are shown.

When results from Table2 have reached end of their data then results from Table3 are shown.

When results of Table3 reaches end of the data then there is nothing to display
Please advise

Comment: There is an approach of using "UNION ALL" but im concerned about efficiency in Database side

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own `PagingSource` which will accept multiple `PagingSource` in a constructor and load them one after another.

```
class MultipleSourcesSource<T : Any>(
    val sources: List<PagingSource<Int, T>>
) : PagingSource<Int, T>() {

    private var currentIndex = 0

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, T> {
        if (currentIndex == sources.size) {
            return LoadResult.Page(
               data = emptyList(),
               prevKey = null,
               nextKey = null
            )
        }

        val result = sources[currentIndex].load(params)
        currentIndex++

        return LoadResult.Page(
               data = result.data,
               prevKey = if (currentIndex == 0) currentIndex else currentIndex - 1,
               nextKey = currentIndex
        )
        return result
    }

    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, T>) = null
}
```

You also will have to create `PagingSource`'s for your tables:

```
class Table1DataSource(
    private val database: MyDatabase
) : PagingSource<Int, Item>() {

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Item> {
        val items = database.getData() // get data from your source
        return LoadResult.Page(
            data = items,
            prevKey = null,
            nextKey = null
        )
    }

    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Table1Item>) = null
}
```

And finally you can just use `MultipleSourcesSource` for load your data:

```
val mediator = MultipleSourcesSource(listOf(
    // here are table sources
))

// Create a Pager with the mediator
val pager = Pager(
    config = PagingConfig(pageSize = pageSize),
    pagingSourceFactory = { mediator }
)
.flow
.collect { results -> 
    // TODO: collect results
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate the quick response..

but in this case...
 first page will be from table 1, second page will be from table 2 and so on ... 

but we needed first all results from table 1 then table 2 and so on...

Comment: You can just remember the last row of result from a table N and when counter will be on the last data source, just set in on 0 and read again from the datasource #1

Comment: Hi @Mikhail I really appreciate the quick reply what worked for me was ConcatAdapter it just worked out of the box for me..

I hooked up 2 instances of pagingAdapter to ConcatAdapter
instance1 i passed in table1
instance2 i passed in table2

Answer (score 0):

ConcatAdapter fixed the use case for me.

I hooked up 2 instances of pagingAdapter to ConcatAdapter
instance1 I passed in a pagingsource of table1
instance2 I passed in a pagingsource of table2

https://developersbreach.com/merge-multiple-adapters-with-concatadapter-android/